# Spring Hiberbate SaaS reload databases information

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, saas

I am using Spring 2.3 and Hibernate 4.0. I have also implemented Software as service (SaaS) successfully in my project. 
When my project starts I have to give information to all databases to load from XML file but problem is when I want to inform new database to load information from XML then without restarting application it is not allowing me to do so.
How can I solve this problem? 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look just a matter of reloading the information - if that would be the case, you could move your DB information into properties (which is recommended anyways) and then use a solution like [this](https://github.com/Unicon/springframework-addons/wiki/Auto-reloading-properties-files) or [LiveRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/liverebel/).

However, since we're talking about open DB connections, you would need to make sure that:  
- the previous datasource would close gracefully 
- Spring actually constructs a new datasource with your new connection details 
- the existing open/ongoing connections would be completed 
- that new connections use the new datasource - which is definitely non-trivial.

My suggestion is to **restart** - if you're really dealing with an application that has such a high SLA that it really doesn't accept a brief restart, then you should probably have the infrastructure in place to work with multiple nodes already - in which case you can always restart them sequentially (not to go into to much detail).

Hope that helps.

Comment: My problem not related to change database password or information but problem related to add more tenants to SaaS implementation without restart server.

Comment: Adding a new tenant should not require reloading anything and should definitely not require a server restart. Can you provide some info about what you're using the represent tenants in the DB?